# Calculate basic statistics in R

Tags: r, statistics, mean, genetics

I am a noob when using R.

My experiment: I have 300 genotypes, each one planted in 6 different locations. For every genotype in every location I have a measure of the yield.

What I would like to do: I would like to calculate the mean, standard deviation and standard error for every genotype, first using the yield data of the 6 locations. Later, I want to calculate the same statistical parameters for only 5 locations and then 4 locations.

This is example of my desired output:

[image]

I have been searching for days, but I cannot find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your data:

```
library(data.table)
dt= data.table(genotype=sample(1:10,size=20,replace=T),
               location=sample(1:6,size=20,replace=T),
               yield=round(runif(20,1000,1500)))
```

Then, first thing to do is to take the mean of *yield*, by *genotype*:

```
m1 = dt[,.(mean_6_locations=mean(yield)),by=genotype]
```

After that, assuming that you know which locations to exclude, here is the mean of 5 and 4 locations respectively:

```
m2 = dt[!location %in% c(10),.(mean_5_locations=mean(yield)),by=genotype]

m3 = dt[!location %in% c(5,10),.(mean_4_locations=mean(yield)),by=genotype]
```

Note that location 10 is excluded for mean of 5 locations, similarly locations 5 and 10 are excluded for mean of 4 locations.

Lastly, you need to merge everything into a single table:

```
m12 = merge(m1,m2)
m123 = merge(m12,m3)
print(m123)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting thing, and I would do it with Monte Carlo "like" methods. Definitely I would encourage nonparametric methods because the dimensionality of the data doesn't support distributional assumptions.
Assume genotype doesn't matter, and aggregate over the six locations [or 5 or 4]... to make a distribution of means. The corresponding quintile of one specific genotypes mean corresponding number of locations mean tells you a lot more about the genotype than the mean itself. Also the standard error of means falls out of that distribution.
The standard deviation of this distribution similarly let's you know the standard deviation among means and allows for significance testing. 
I know this answer is a little tangent, but building a distribution for six locations and taking the standard deviation of that doesn't tell you much. 
Similarly,If you take the standard deviation of all rows and build a distribution of standard deviations, you can see how tightly a given genotypes standard deviation is relative to the population again just by using a quintile. 
I assume the optimal genotype would be high quintile in the mean distribution and low quintile in the standard deviation distribution for a given location or among all locations. Depending of course on the specific question being addressed